# Cross-validating kriging results using gstat R from hyperparameter

Tags: r, gstat, cross-validation

I have a large dataset that doesn't require kriging (it would take too much time to compute anyways). But I'm interested to find the optimal number of samples that would be sufficient in order to apply kriging with a reasonable accuracy. What I would like to do is to compare the kriging results on the sampled datasets (N=500,750,1000,etc..) with the observed points and display a curve of the RMSE results from cross-validation. Is there a way to achieve this using gstat in R ? In scikit-learn, I would tune hyper-parameters with a grid search. N (number of samples) would be this hyper-parameter, but I don't know if I can achieve this using R. I noticed that a *krige.cv* function exists in gstat, would it be the way to go ?

Comment: Have you read the help for `krige.cv`? Would you be re-estimating your variogram from your sample? Have you used `gstat` before? Do you know how to fit a standard kriging model and get estimates and uncertainties at locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will split a dataset into a "train" and a "test" set, then fit a kriging model to the training data and use that to predict at the test locations. The returned object has the values of the prediction and its variance alongside its "ground truth" value from the data:

```
splitfit <- function(data, size, f, m){
    train = sample(nrow(data), size)
    trainData = data[train,]
    testData = data[-train,]

    testTruth = model.frame(f, data=testData)[,1]

    fit = krige(f, trainData, testData, model=m)
    fit$truth=testTruth
    fit

}
```

Usage example - first set up some data:

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
m <- vgm(.59, "Sph", 874, .04)
```

Then for a test fit using 150 points leaving five to predict at:

```
> f = splitfit(meuse, 150, log(zinc)~1, m)
> f
         coordinates var1.pred  var1.var    truth
58  (179792, 332035)  5.914287 0.1558987 6.068426
69  (179470, 331125)  5.521936 0.2236325 6.966024
82  (179007, 330727)  6.388311 0.1160167 6.529419
133 (180478, 331822)  5.113655 0.2109839 4.779123
138 (180467, 331694)  5.066423 0.2197835 4.890349
```

Now you can compute whatever test score you want to use from the predicted, variance, and truth values, do that for a number of 150-point samples to get an average of those, then repeat for 100 samples, 50 samples whatever until you've gone over or under whatever threshold you are interested in.

Note how you might be averaging lots of things with uncertainty, or comparing things with uncertain things.... be careful...

Two more functions that might be useful - first one that repeats over a number of splits and computes the mean of the mean square errors over the test points:

```
splitfits <- function(data, size, f, m, n){
    errs = sapply(1:n, function(i){
        f = splitfit(data, size, f, m)
        mean((f$var1.pred-f$truth)^2)
    })
    mean(errs)
}
```

And then one that does that over a number of training set sizes:

```
splints <- function(data, sizes, f, m, n){
    err = sapply(sizes, function(size){
        splitfits(data, size, f, m, n)
    })
    data.frame(size=sizes, err=err)
}
```

Then you can do 500 splits with each of a number of training set sizes thus:

```
f = splints(meuse, seq(10, 140,by=10), log(zinc)~1, m, 500)
plot(f$size, f$err)
```

[image]

which shows how as the training set size increases the mean-mean-square error decreases. At the left of this plot it is only using 10 points to estimate the other 145, and on the right it is using 140 points to estimate 15.

Comment: Thanks for your very insightful answer. OK, I think I understand why I may have to be careful when comparing RMSE (for instance) between differents models and datasets. I guess that I won't be able to mean the RMSE results. I may be able to plot several curves with ggplot2 for each models though. That may do the job.

Comment: Added a couple of other functions to do something like that maybe (and plot with base graphics).

Comment: Thanks again, I was currently coding something similar but your code seems neater than mine ! I will add some more code later on